# HTML Jump to certain part of another page by clicking on a part of an image

Tags: html, image, href

Okay so I just began with doing HTML/CSS/PHP for school. I made a webpage by just adding one image (made in Photoshop) and putting it in an image map. I have 2 buttons and they both are clickable and need to redirect to another page. All my webpages contain only one image. Now my question is, how to jump to another page and reaching the bottom of this image (bottom of the page) when clicking on one of the buttons? (If I click on one of the buttons it automatically loads the next page at the top)

Hope one of you guys can help me out here!

**EDIT:**

added images from comments because they contains the code:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: We need to see your code!

Comment: I second what Chris says.

Comment: This is my first page HTML code: http://prntscr.com/9ffwiq                                            This is the second page (the one that it needs to be linked to): http://prntscr.com/9ffx6w                                                                                  All the img names and comments etc are in Dutch, so if u want to know what a certain thing means, just ask me.

Comment: I would say... don't make web pages like that. You should use HTML and CSS (JavaScript if necessary), and not rely entirely on image maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an element with an id below that image and then add the id to the link.

This is the link:

```
<a href="otherpage.html#bottom">Link to image</a>
```

This is the other page:

```
<img src="img/yourimage.png" /><div id="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: Oh okay, thank you! I'm going to try that. I'll let you know if it worked.

Comment: Note that this will only work if your content is bigger than your browser's window, else there is nothing to scroll obviously. If this is the case you'll have to add more space - even though I'd try to avoid this because you want your site to be as dymanic as possible.

Comment: Do I need to position that div to the bottom of my other page in CSS?

Comment: Figured it out! Just did border 0 left 0 and positioned it to relative. Thanks! Got me rid of some stress

Answer (score 1):

Under your image, just add a element with an id property and add an anchor in the button url.

Page1.php :

```
<a href="page2.php#image-bottom">Go to bottom</a>
```

Page2.php :

```
<img src="image.png" alt="image">
<span id="image-bottom"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If im understanding you correctly, you want your link to go to a specific
scroll point down the target page.
So instead of loading target.html and being at the top of the page
you want to be somewhere lower on the page. or have some lower content
be at the top of the screen when loaded.

in the starting_page.html your link currently looks like this

```
 <a href='target_page.html'>click here</a>
```

change that to

```
 <a href='target_page.html#Position_1_on_page'>click here</a>
```

and then edit your target_page.html and put

```
 <div id='Position_1_on_page'></div>
```

now when someone clicks that link it will load the target_page.html and scroll
it down so that the div called Position_1_on_page will be the topmost element
on the page once it loads